# Loading a form by ajax

Tags: forms, ajax, nodes

I've been stucked on problem since two weeks.
Basically, what i'am trying to do is:
1) Create a page, in which there is an link ("Click me"), 
When i click on it, a form is fetched from another page and added to the current page.
The form is correctly fetched, but it seems any javascript/ajax related to the form is lost.
I have a custom  Ajax submit callback for this form, on the page of the form(submit button has class ajax-processed), it is working correctly but when fetched by Ajax(submit button does not has the class ajax-processed), it doesn't.

Below is my code:

```
<?php

function custom_preprocess_page(&$vars){

  drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.ajax');
  drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.form');
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module','custom').'/custom.js', 'file');
}

/**
 * Implements hook_menu
 * @return string
 */
function custom_menu() {

    $items['my-test/my_form'] = array(
        'title' => 'Ajax test',
        'description' => 'Page containing form',
        'page callback' => '_custom_retrieve_webform',
        'access callback' => TRUE,
    );

    $items['my-test/retrieve_form'] = array(
        'title' => 'Ajax test',
        'description' => 'Page where form should be loaded by ajax',
        'page callback' => '_custom_retrieve_html',
        'access callback' => TRUE,
    );
    return $items;
}
function _custom_retrieve_html(){
    return '<div id="justadiv"><a class="clickme">'. t('click me'). '</a></div>';
}
function _custom_retrieve_webform(){

   $node = node_load(12);
   $submission = (object) array();
   $enabled = TRUE;
   $preview = FALSE;
   $form= drupal_get_form('webform_client_form_12', $node, $submission, $enabled, $preview);
  return '<div id="myform">'.drupal_render($form).'<div>';
}




function custom_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_12') {
        $nid = $form['#node']->nid;
        $form['submitted']['gender']['#default_value'] = 'M';
        $form['actions']['submit']['#ajax'] = array(
            'callback' => 'mymodule_webform_js_submit',
            'wrapper' => 'webform-client-form-' . $nid,
            'method' => 'replace',
            'effect' => 'fade',
        );

       //$form['#theme']=array('custom_web_form');

       array_unshift($form['#theme'], 'custom_web_form');
    }
}

function mymodule_webform_js_submit($form, $form_state) {
      // define the $sid variable (submission id from webform)
      $sid = $form_state['values']['details']['sid'];
      // if we have a sid then we know the form was properly submitted, otherwise, we'll just return the existing $form array
      if ($sid) {

        dsm($sid);

        $confirmation = array(
          '#type' => 'markup',
          '#markup' => 'sucess',
        );
        // return the confirmation message
        return $confirmation;
      }
      else {
        // return the form
        return $form;
      }
    }
```

My js:

```
(function($){

    Drupal.behaviors.my_custom= {

        attach:function(context,settings){
            $('a.clickme').click(function(e){
                $('#justadiv').load('/d7/my-test/ajax_loaded #webform-client-form-12', function(response, status, xhr) {

                    Drupal.attachBehaviors('#webform-client-form-12');


                });
                Drupal.attachBehaviors($('#webform-client-form-12')[0]);
            });

        }



    }

})(jQuery)
```

CAn anyone tell me what is wrong ?

Comment: solution: https://drupal.org/node/2009252

Answer (score 2):

Solution posted here:

basically:

> You need to generate the javascript settings for the form, and send
>   them to the browser to be merged with the existing settings. Without
>   doing this, any AJAX on your form will not work.

https://drupal.org/node/2009252

Comment: See Why are some questions or answers removed? http://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion